# vue show js 's error :TypeError: "this is undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make a dynamic water pipe with water flowing. The front picture is an error message.

[image]

[image]

The following picture is a method in the method in the vue page. I don't know if it will report an error. If you don't call this method, nothing will be reported.

[image]

The following code is the js file that introduces the vue page

```js
//构造函数

function Createline(config) {

    this.c = 0;

    this.lines = [];

    var self = this;

    //初始化线

    (function (self){

        if(config.fx == "w"){

            var number =  config.canvas_w / (config.width + config.width/2 + config.jiange*2);

            number = Math.ceil(number) + 1;

            for(var n = 0 ; n < number ; n++){

                var mxx = config.canvas_w - n*(config.width+config.width/2+config.jiange*2);

                var lines_data = {

                    mx:mxx,

                    lx:mxx - config.width,

                    my:config.my,

                    ly:config.ly,

                    vx:config.vx,

                    vy:config.vy,

                }

                self.lines.push(lines_data);

                var lines_data2 = {

                    mx:mxx-config.width-config.jiange,

                    lx:mxx-config.width-config.jiange-config.width/2,

                    my:config.my,

                    ly:config.ly,

                    vx:config.vx,

                    vy:config.vy,

                }

                self.lines.push(lines_data2);

            }

        }

        if(config.fx == "h"){

            var number =  config.canvas_w / (config.width + config.width/2 + config.jiange*2);

            number = Math.ceil(number) + 1;

            for(var n = 0 ; n < number ; n++){

                var myy = config.canvas_h - n*(config.width+config.width/2+config.jiange*2);

                var lines_data3 = {

                    mx:config.mx,

                    lx:config.lx,

                    my:myy,

                    ly:myy - config.width,

                    vx:config.vx,

                    vy:config.vy,

                }

                self.lines.push(lines_data3);

                var lines_data4 = {

                    mx:config.mx,

                    lx:config.lx,

                    my:myy-config.width-config.jiange,

                    ly:myy-config.width-config.jiange-config.width/2,

                    vx:config.vx,

                    vy:config.vy,

                }

                self.lines.push(lines_data4);

            }

        }

    })(self);

}

//开始

Createline.prototype.begin = function (element,config) {

    var canvasObj  = document.getElementById(element);

    var self = this;

    var canvas = {

        line_w: config.line_w || 3, //线条厚度

        vx: config.vx || 0,//x轴运动速度

        vy:config.vy || 0,//Y轴速度

        color:config.color || "blue",//线条颜色

        canvas_w:config.canvas_w || 0,//画布宽度

        canvas_h:config.canvas_h || 0,//画布高度

        mx: config.mx || 0,//线的开始位置X坐标

        my: config.my || 0,//线的开始位置Y坐标

        lx: config.lx || 0,//线的结束位置X坐标

        ly: config.ly || 0,//线的结束位置Y坐标

        fx:config.fx || "w",//运动方向 w 水平 ，h: 垂直

        width:config.width || 20,//线的长度

        jiange:config.jiange || 10, //线的间隔

    }

    if(canvasObj.getContext("2d")){

        canvas.ctx = canvasObj.getContext("2d"),

        canvasObj.width = canvas.canvas_w;

        canvasObj.height = canvas.canvas_h;

    }else{

        console.log("当前环境不支持canvas");

        return null;

    }

    setInterval(function(){

        self.createline(self,canvas);

        if(canvas.fx == "w"){

            self.updateline_w(self,canvas);

        }

        if(canvas.fx == "h"){

            self.updateline_h(self,canvas);

        }

        self.addline(self,canvas);

    },config.time);



    return canvas.ctx;

}

//画线

Createline.prototype.createline = function(self,canvas){

    var content = canvas.ctx;

        content.clearRect(0,0,canvas.canvas_w,canvas.canvas_h);

        for(var i = 0 ; i < self.lines.length ; i++){

            content.beginPath();

            content.moveTo(self.lines[i].mx,self.lines[i].my);

            //线经过的转折点或结束点

            content.lineTo(self.lines[i].lx,self.lines[i].ly);

            //线条宽度

            content.lineWidth = canvas.line_w;

            content.strokeStyle = canvas.color;

            content.stroke();

            //线条颜色

            content.closePath();

            //画线

        }

}

//改变数据 水平运动

Createline.prototype.updateline_w = function(self,canvas){

    for (var i = 0 ; i < self.lines.length ; i++) {

        self.lines[i].mx = self.lines[i].mx + self.lines[i].vx;

        self.lines[i].lx = self.lines[i].lx + self.lines[i].vx;

    }

    //超出画布的线条从数组内删除，减少系统消耗

    var cnt = [];

    for (var j = 0 ;j < self.lines.length ; j++) {

        if(self.lines[j].lx > canvas.canvas_w){

            cnt.push(j);

        }

    }

    for(var k = 0; k < cnt.length ; k++){

        self.lines.splice(k,1);

    }

}



//改变数据 垂直运动

Createline.prototype.updateline_h = function(self,canvas){

    for (var i = 0 ; i < self.lines.length ; i++) {

        self.lines[i].my =  self.lines[i].my + lines[i].vy;

        self.lines[i].ly =  self.lines[i].ly + lines[i].vy;

    }

    //超出画布的线条从数组内删除，减少系统消耗

    var cnt = [];

    for (var j = 0 ;j <  self.lines.length ; j++) {

        if( self.lines[j].ly > canvas.canvas_h){

            cnt.push(j);

        }

    }

    for(var k = 0; k < cnt.length ; k++){

        self.lines.splice(k,1);

    }

}

//增加线

Createline.prototype.addline = function(self,canvas){

    var length = self.lines.length;

    //横线

    if(canvas.fx == "w"){

        //判断是否需要生成线

        if(self.lines[length-1].lx > 0){

            //起点位置 等于 左右一根线的坐标减去间隔

            var ww = self.lines[length - 1].lx - canvas.jiange;

            //判断长短

            if(self.c == 0){

                var jg =  canvas.width;

                self.c = 10;

            }else{

                var jg =  canvas.width/2;

                self.c = 0;

            }

            var lxx = ww - jg;



            var data = {

                mx:ww,

                lx:lxx,



                my:canvas.my,

                ly:canvas.ly,

                vx:canvas.vx,

                vy:canvas.vy,

            }

            self.lines.push(data);

        }

    }



    //垂直

    if(canvas.fx == "h"){

        if(length>0){

            //判断是否需要生成线

            if(self.lines[length-1].ly > 0){

                //起点位置 等于 左右一根线的坐标减去间隔

                var my = self.lines[length - 1].ly - canvas.jiange;

                //判断长短

                if(c == 0){

                    var jg =  canvas.width;

                    c = 10;

                }else{

                    var jg =  canvas.width/2;

                    c = 0;

                }

                var ly = my - jg;



                var data = {

                    mx:canvas.mx,

                    lx:canvas.lx,

                    my:my,

                    ly:ly,

                    vx:canvas.vx,

                    vy:canvas.vy,

                }

                self.lines.push(data);

            }



        }else{

            var data = {

                mx:canvas.mx,

                my:canvas.my,

                lx:canvas.lx,

                ly:canvas.ly,

                vx:canvas.vx,

                vy:canvas.vy,

            }



            self.lines.push(data);

        }

    }



}

export{

    Createline

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `new` when creating a instance for a constructor that uses `this`:

```
var cre = new Createline(data);
```

When a function is executed using `new` it does the following:

```
function User(name) {
  // this = {};  (implicitly)

  // add properties to this
  this.name = name;
  this.isAdmin = false;

  // return this;  (implicitly)
}
```